# How to catch imageclick event in controller of extjs4

Tags: image, extjs4, click

I am working in extjs4. i have extjs view  as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.kp.Word.SearchWord', {
extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    id:'WordId',
    alias:'widget.SearchWord',
    bodyPadding: 30,
    defaults:{
        margin:'0 20 0 70'
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
   },

            items:[
                   {

                       xtype:'textfield',
                       fieldLabel:'Enter the Word:',
                       name:'Word',
                     //  height:30,
                       border:false,
                       allowBlank:false,
                       emptyText: 'Enter the word',
                       id:'wordtext'
                   },
                   {
                       xtype: 'image',
                        width: 30,
                        height: 22,
                        src: 'http://www.asien-news.de/wp-content/uploads/new-york.jpg',
                  }
                   ],});
```

I want to call controller's function on click of above image. So how to catch image click event in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [listeners](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-cfg-listeners) propetry from [Observable](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable) class;

> A config object containing one or more event handlers to be added to
>   this object during initialization. This should be a valid listeners
>   config object as specified in the addListener example for attaching
>   multiple handlers at once.

Simply bind it on the underlying element, like this:

```
listeners: {
    el: {
        click: function() {
            Ext.Msg.alert("Image clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

here is a [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JkezA/1/).